# There is extra vertical space between block-level elements when setting initial-scale=1.x in Chrome

Tags: html, css, viewport

If I add the following meta tag to my mobile web page , there is extra  space between block-level elements in vertical direction.

`<meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1.2,user-scalable=no" id="metaViewwport">`

How to solve the problem?

The complete code:

```
 <html>
<head lang="en">
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1.2,user-scalable=no" id="metaViewwport">
    <title>test</title>
    <style type="text/css">
        html,body
        {width:100%;height: 100%;margin:0px;padding:0px;}

        .slide-container
        {height:200px;width:100%;background-color:black;color:white;
        box-sizing:border-box;
        box-shadow:none;
        border:0px;
        padding:0px;
        margin:0px;
        }
    </style>
 </head>
<body>
<article style="height:100%;width:100%;">
    <section class="slide-container" style="">
        1
    </section>
    <section class="slide-container">2</section>
    <section class="slide-container">
       3
    </section>
    <section class="slide-container">
       4
    </section>

</article>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

your problem is your viewport more than likely. Its set to 1.2, rather than 1.

add this line instead

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
```

Comment: you can add user-scalable=no

Comment: it is preferable to use <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1"> instead of user-scalable=no

Comment: Hi, I  need to set initial-scale=xxx to adapt to different devices.

Comment: I  was developing a H5 slides auto-creating tools .  The end user design their slides in some standard stage (320x480 or other), then render the design in different devices. To make the elements in design keep same proportion  (distance ,shape) in horizontal direction.  I  use the simplest way to do the device adaption---scale according to device-width.  For example , in iPhone6 ,the device-width is 375px ,and the user design their slides in a 320px width stage. Then the scale woud be  375/320.

Answer (score -1):

I  fixed by add height=device-height to the meta viewport. Just like:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1.171875,height=device-height,width=320px, user-scalable=no">
```